# Solr do not find record if query string starts with short word

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr 4, and I have length filter factory in place

```
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="99"/>
```

If my query string starts with the word that has less than 3 characters, solr will not return any results. I was not expecting this to be the problem because I am using LengthFilterFactory. Here are the examples:

title is: "**In the close future...**"

if I search `q:In the close future`, solr returns nothing
if I search `q:the close future`, solr finds the record

title is: "**I have some solr problem**"
same happens as above...

I can not allow for words shorter than 3 characters to be searched, but I was not expecting that if I use word shorter than 3 characters, it would cause solr to fail. Maybe LengthFilterFactory is not the problem here?

Here is my query example:

```
INFO: [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={mm=100%25&json.nl=flat&fl=id&start=0&sort=date_0_i+desc,hour_0_i+desc&fq=type_s:(1+5+6+8+9+10)&fq=site_i:1&fq=terms_txt:I+have+some+solr+problem&fq=date_in_i:[20050101+TO+*]&fq=date_in_i:[*+TO+20171012]&fq=language_is:0&rows=10&bq=&q=I+have+some+solr+problem&tie=0.1&defType=edismax&omitHeader=true&qf=terms_txt&wt=json} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
```

Here is my schema bellow. I will show you the field definition for the filed that I am searching from. Anyone have any idea what is wrong here ?

```
<fieldType name="text_general_example" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>          
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(^|\s)([^\-\_&amp;\s]+([\-\_&amp;]+[^\-\_&amp;\s]*)+)(?=(\s|$))" replacement="$1MжџљМ$2 $2" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\bMжџљМ([^\s]*?)\b[\-_&amp;]+" replacement="MжџљМ$1" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\bMжџљМ([^\s]*?)\b[\-_&amp;]+" replacement="MжџљМ$1" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\bMжџљМ([^\s]*?)\b[\-_&amp;]+" replacement="MжџљМ$1" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="MжџљМ" replacement="" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\w)&amp;(\w)" replacement="$1and$2" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="99"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\b[\-_]+\b" replacement="" />
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\w)&amp;(\w)" replacement="$1and$2" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="99"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: is it exactly the query you're using?you don't use any field in the query?

Comment: @Mysterion I have added my query example to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is, that if you're searching for

```
field:I have a problem
```

than, after parsing you will actually get the following query `field:I defaultField:have defaultField:a ...`, where default field is usually specified in your `solrconfig.xml`. You could as well debug these problems by yourself, by using parameter `debugQuery`

Some of the tokens will be eliminated, and that's the reason why you didn't get proper results. To do a proper query, you need to enclose query with double quotes `"`

Comment: Thanks, but I can not enclose mu query with double quotes, because I do not want to use phrase search. Where is the default field definition in solrconfig.xml ? I can not find it.

Comment: I found it, and changing default field seems to fix my problem.